# Why v-bind parameters cannot reference a variable in an object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In the code below, only `#3` works. Why I cannot pass the variable `showAlert1` from `alertObj`?

Also, how does `#3` work? does it pull the first boolean variable from the object?

**PS.** I am not sure why StackOverflow does not show Vue as an option when doing the code (or how to import it properly)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    alertObj: [{
      showAlert1: true
    }]
  }
})
```

```css
.alert {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <div v-bind:class="{alert:alertObj.showAlert1}">#1</div>
  <div v-bind:class="{alert:showAlert1}">#2</div>
  <div v-bind:class="{alert:alertObj}">#3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `alertObj` is an array, you need the index first. `alertObj[0].showAlert1`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, when you bind a class with a variable, that is next to the colan, it is evaluated to a boolean.

`alert:alertObj.showAlert1`, in your example the `alertObj.showAlert1` will be evaluated as `Boolean(alertObj.showAlert1)`.

So,

1. alertObj.showAlert1 will return `undefined` alertObj doesn't have a key showAlert1
2. alert:showAlert1 will return `undefined` because you don't have a property  showAlert1
3. alertObj will return `true`, so the class is applied

Comment: Why does alertObj by itself return true? And alertObj DOES have a key inside it named "showAlert1", I don't understand exactly what 'key' means...

Comment: because it has an array. Only values like undefined, null, false, "" will be evaluated to false.